# how to solve error of when apply random color to buttons angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

In my component I apply random color to multiple buttons. Color applies successfully but following error shows me on console.

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'background-color: #85B228'. Current value: 'background-color: #505563'.
```

This is my code:

```
getRandomColor2() {
    var length = 6;
    var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var hex = '#';
    while(length--) hex += chars[(Math.random() * 16) | 0];
    return hex;
  }
<button type="button" class="btn" style="color:black" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getRandomColor2()}"
```

Comment: How often is that function called?  Do you intend a new color at every screen repaint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ts-code do this:

```
class XComponent {
    randomColor2 = getRandomColor2();
    //...
}
```

And in your html-template use the value like this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': randomColor2}"
```

The color will only be randomly chose once, on component creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Change detection mechanism. Change Detection will take the internal state of object, arrays and make it somehow visible to the user interface.

You can use it inside getRandomColor2() after doing your logic,

for example,

```
getRandomColor2({
    //do your logic here
    this.changeDetecionRef.detectChanges();
}
```